# Android custom text style

Tags: android, textview

If I want display TextView as below :

```
-------------display-------------
```

The "display" field is a dynamic data, and the View is TextView, include text and lines on both sides, is any suggestion for the xml build? Or maybe can do it programmatically?

Comment: try this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya you can do like below code.

In this code, both side line will adjust according to width,

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#D0D0D0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Your text goes here" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#D0D0D0" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank, I just found the answer like this !

Comment: @AndyWu Ok, You got your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.xml` to store the dash line as text and use `String.format` method to put dynamic text in your `textview`

Put the below line in **string.xml:**

```
<string name="dash_line">-----%1$s-----</string>
```

Now you can use the above `string` to set dashed line with dynamic data in your `textview as follows:

```
String formattedstring = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.dash_line), yourStringToShow);
yourTextView.setText(formattedstring );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show some drawables, Create a `Shape` drawable as line. i.e. Name below file as dashed_line.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:dashWidth="3dp" android:dashGap="1dp" android:color="@color/black" android:width="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

and use it as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/dashed_line">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Or If you simply want to put as a string, '------' on both side then just add it dynamically while setting text i.e.

```
String display="display"; 
textview.setText("---------"+display+"--------");
```